# Using GPIOzero play an MP3 sound file whilst a button is held and an alternative MP3 when button is released (Python, Pygame, Raspberry Pi))

Tags: python, button, pygame, raspberry-pi, mp3

So what I am trying to do is have an MP3 playing when a button on my solderless Breadboard is not pressed and a different one playing when the button is held - best popular example is the 'Deal or No Deal' phone if the Banker on the other end was just a recorded message.  I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B using the GPIO pins to hook up a button on a breadboard (later to include a speaker bonnet but that's later me's problem).  Here is some code;

Below is the main script

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

button = Button(2)

while True:
    if button.is_pressed == True:
        import playLeft       #run the playLeft script when button is pressed
    else:
        import playRight   #run the playRight script when not pressed
```

playLeft script

```
#import the Pygame sound module
import pygame

#designate where the files are located declared in variables
path = "/home/pi/"
sound_files = "phoneLEFT.mp3"

#initialise Pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
speaker_volume = 1.0  #100% speaker volume
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(speaker_volume) #sets the mixer volume to the speaker_volume variable

for sound_file in sound_files: #iterating loop playing the files in the sound_files variable 
    pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/john/phoneLEFT.mp3") #using the pygame module loads the sound file...
    pygame.mixer.music.play() #plays the sound file
```

playRight script

```
#import the Pygame sound module
import pygame

#designate where the files are located declared in variables
path = "/home/pi/"
sound_files = "handsetright.mp3"

#initialise Pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
speaker_volume = 1.0  #100% speaker volume
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(speaker_volume) #sets the mixer volume to the speaker_volume variable

for sound_file in sound_files: #iterating loop playing the files in the sound_files variable 
    pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/john/handsetright.mp3") #using the pygame module loads the sound file...
    pygame.mixer.music.play() #plays the sound file
```

The current result is that upon running the code it will play the 'Right' script, will accept the button being held and go onto play the 'Left' script but upon release of the button will not return to playing the 'Right' script.  Can any Genius' out there give us a hand?  Taking any clever recommendations :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Always comment your code like a violent psychopath will be maintaining it and they know where you live  ;)
from pygame import mixer     #imports Mixer class from the Pygame module to run the sound
from gpiozero import Button     #imports the Button element only from GPIOzero
import time     #imports the time class to slow the loop, saving processing.

button = Button(2)     #designates the GPIO pin 2 to the physical button input it is attached to     
mixer.init()     #instantiate the mixer class from Pygame

def ringing():     #a funtion to manage loading, playing and unloading the PhoneLEFT.mp3 (Ringing when set down)
    mixer.music.stop()   #stop the current soundfile, which will be the alternate one running
    mixer.music.set_volume(1.0) #sets the mixer volume 
    mixer.music.load('phoneLEFT.mp3')   #Load the named sound file located in the same folder (Current Working Directory) 
    mixer.music.play() #plays the loaded sound file

def talking():     #a funtion to manage loading, playing and unloading the handsetright.mp3 (Informational when handset used)
    mixer.music.stop()   #stop the current soundfile, which will be the alternate one running
    mixer.music.set_volume(1.0) #sets the mixer volume 
    mixer.music.load('handsetright.mp3')   #Load the named sound file located in the same folder (CWD)
    mixer.music.play() #plays the sound file
    

while True:     #initialise a while loop
    button.when_pressed = ringing    #when button is held perform the 'ringing' function
    button.when_released = talking   #when the button is not held perform the 'talking' function
    time.sleep(0.05)   #slows the while loop to iterate every 0.05seconds
```

So in the end i changed up the idea of having different scripts importing in the sound and thatwas the begining of the end.  There was a reasonable amount of messing about with the updates of Pygame but once it was all back together this above was a result